# ng-repeat Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null after data is reloaded 3 times

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using Slick Slider(https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) to show a horizontal slider at the bottom of my webpage:

```
<div class="container" ng-if="loop">
  <div class="row">
    <slick dots="true" init-onload="true" data="schedule" center-mode="false" infinite="false" speed="300" slides-to-show="4" touch-move="true" slides-to-scroll="1" class="slider one-time">
      <div ng-repeat="x in schedule">
        <div class="status-x-current">
          <a class="x-button" ng-if="x.title == ''" data-ng-click="showRes(workplace, x)">Click here to to do something</a>
          <h3 ng-if="x.title != ''" id = "x_title1" class="x-slider-title">Titel: {{x.title}}</h3>
          <h3 ng-if="x.title != ''" id = "x_time1" class="x-slider-time">{{x.date}}</h3>
      </div>
      </div>
    </slick>
</div>
```

the input data for ng-repeat(schedule) is reloaded from server every 10 seconds like this:

```
 (function tick() {
      ScheduleService.getReservation({}, function(response) {
          $scope.schedule = response.schedule;//I already determined that the response is correct and the same every time
          $timeout(tick, 10000);
      });

  })();
```

This works fine the first 2 times schedule is  reloaded, but after the third time it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
    at angular.js?body=1:3851
    at forEach (angular.js?body=1:304)
    at Object.$AnimateProvider.$get.enter (angular.js?body=1:3850)
    at angular.js?body=1:18726
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js?body=1:5421)
    at ngRepeatAction (angular.js?body=1:18724)
    at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (angular.js?body=1:11300)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js?body=1:11396)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js?body=1:11635)
    at done (angular.js?body=1:7636)(anonymous function) @ angular.js?body=1:9038$get @ angular.js?body=1:6649$get.Scope.$digest @ angular.js?body=1:11408$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js?body=1:11635done @ angular.js?body=1:7636completeRequest @ angular.js?body=1:7802xhr.onreadystatechange @ angular.js?body=1:7758
```

I'm 100% sure schedule is exactly the same every time it's reloaded. I think it's because of `init-onload="true" data="schedule"`. The error doesn't occur after I remove that line from the html. But removing that line causes slick to behave incorrectly. Slick will cram all the slides in to the screen instead of only showing 4(slides-to-show="4") when removing `init-onload="true" data="schedule"`.

Comment: Hi MeesterPatat, any luck with this issue? I'm having a similar issue which only happens after second data load

Comment: No I just decided to not use slick slider.